# Accessing Redmine repository: directories and files without extension

Tags: git, redmine

I've connected a Git repository with Redmine. Via Redmine GUI I'm trying to access files/directories and some of them just got me back error 404 "The entry or revision was not found in the repository."

I tried to access directory `client` but got 404.

From `production.log`  I noticed the following:

```
 Started GET "/projects/MYPROJECT/repository/revisions/master/show/client.html"       for 212.57.58.2 at 2013-10-29 15:11:56 +0100
 Processing by RepositoriesController#show as HTML
 Parameters: {"id"=>"MYPROJECT", "rev"=>"master", "path"=>"client.html"}
 Current user: pavel (id=4)
 Rendered common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (0.2ms)
 Completed 404 Not Found in 50ms (Views: 22.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

As you can see redmine tries to access **client.html** for all directories and for all files without extension.

Why does redmine adds **.html** and how to avoid it?

Comment: Please show us the .htaccess file from your server. Does it have "Options +Indexes" option?